# Jquery show/hide function nearly there

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need some simple tweaks which I'm struggling to get right.

Here's my JS code and a Fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav a").click(function(){
  var id =  $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.split('_');
  $("#menu_container div").hide(); 
  $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show();
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KUtY5/1/

Basically all I need is for the changes to have a transition effect and most importantly I need the first box to display on page load.

Thank you.

Comment: _"all I need is for the changes to have a transition effect"_ What transition effect?

Comment: Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slide` to create the effect:

```
$("#menu_container div").slideUp("slow", function() {
     $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).slideDown("slow");
});
```

As for show on page load, either call `.show()` on load or remove the `display:none;` in the CSS for that specific div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to get the first div and show it by default and **[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** for fade in effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu_container div').eq(0).show();
    $("#nav a").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.split('_');
        $("#menu_container div").hide();
        $("#menu_container #menu_" + id[1]).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KUtY5/223/)**